# Simular evento click lista de tag Span

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Eu tenho uma pagina onde exibo alguns áudios quando o usuário clica e disparado o som.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplo **HTML**

```
<td><span class="audiospeak" data-lang="en" data-aid="of">of</span></td>
<td><span class="audiospeak" data-lang="en" data-aid="and">and</span></td>
```

Agora preciso implementar um botão para tocar todos os sons da pagina com intervalo de 5 segundos.

Tentei o seguinte código

```
jQuery(function($){
    var interval1;
    setTimeout(function(){    
        interval1 = setInterval(function() 
        {
            $('.audiospeak').trigger('click');
        },
        5000);
    },
    5000);
})
```

Porém ele está disparando todos ao mesmo tempo, onde posso estar errando?

Comment: sim, pois voce está dando click em tudo que tem a classe .audiospeak. pode colocar mais codigos do html? Passa o código que monta essa tabela

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que funcione como quer tem que a cada intervalo tocar um som diferente, e não usando diretamente o seletor `$('.audiospeak')` que acerta em todos os sons.
A solução que coloco obtém os audios todos através desse seletor e passa-os para um array. Depois a cada intervalo do temporizador toca um dos sons e remove-o do array.

Exemplo:

```js
$(".audiospeak").on("click", function(){
  $(this).next()[0].play();
});

$("#tocartudo").on("click", function(){
  let sons = []; //array para os sons todos
  $(".audiospeak").each(function(){
    sons.push($(this));
  });

  let timer = setInterval(function(){
    if (sons.length == 0){ //se já não há sons para o timer
      clearInterval(timer);
      $(".audiospeak").removeClass("ativo");
    }
    else {
      sons[0].trigger('click'); //tocar o primeiro do array
      $(".audiospeak").removeClass("ativo");
      sons[0].addClass("ativo");
      sons.splice(0,1); //remover o primeiro do array
    }
  }, 5000); 
});
```

```css
.ativo {
  text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><span class="audiospeak" data-lang="en" data-aid="of">of<i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i></span><audio src="http://sampleswap.org/samples-ghost/LOOPING%20AMBIENCE%20and%20NOISE/837[kb]074_heartbeat-noise-machine.wav.mp3"/></td>
        <td><span class="audiospeak" data-lang="en" data-aid="and">the<i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i></span><audio src="http://sampleswap.org/samples-ghost/LOOPING%20AMBIENCE%20and%20NOISE/746[kb]083_pretty-noise-rhythm.wav.mp3"/></td>
        <td><span class="audiospeak" data-lang="en" data-aid="and">and<i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i></span><audio src="http://sampleswap.org/samples-ghost/LOOPING%20AMBIENCE%20and%20NOISE/641[kb]097_panning-perception.wav.mp3"/></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <button id="tocartudo">Tocar tudo</button>
```

Comment: perfeito!!! Só mais um detalhe, teria como sublinhar a linha que está tocando? Quando tocar o som marcar com uma faixa amarela? exemplo essa imagem http://estudoacelerado.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Marca-texto-min.jpg

Comment: @William Sim. Alterei a resposta adicionando um sublinhado ao som que está a tocar, com base numa das classes CSS definidas. Pode depois estilizar como quiser

Comment: Muito obrigado Isac ficou perfeito!

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma de fazer isso é usando um contador. No caso usei `var conta = 1;` que vai sendo incrementado até que seu valor seja igual ao *número de sons - 1*, e para de tocar.

**Exemplo:**

```js
$(".audiospeak").click(function(){
   // aqui onde os sons são executados
   console.log($(this).data("aid"));
});

jQuery(function($){
   
   $("#tocatudo").click(function(){
      $this = $(this);
      $this.prop("disabled", true); // desabilito o botão
      var sons = $('.audiospeak');
      var conta = 1;
      
      // toca logo o primeiro
      $(sons[0]).trigger('click');
      
      var interval1 = setInterval(function() 
      {
         if(conta == sons.length-1){
            // toca o último e finaliza
            $(sons[sons.length-1]).trigger('click');
            clearInterval(interval1);
            $this.prop("disabled", false); // habilito o botão novamente
            console.log("fim!");
         }else{
            $(sons[conta]).trigger('click');
            conta++;
         }
      },
      5000);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="audiospeak" data-lang="en" data-aid="the">the</span>
<span class="audiospeak" data-lang="en" data-aid="of">of</span>
<span class="audiospeak" data-lang="en" data-aid="and">and</span>
<br>
<button id="tocatudo" type="button">Tocar tudo</button>
```